# Laravel - How to Handle different nested relationships but same model?

Tags: php, optimization, laravel-6

how I can handle this situation in Laravel:

I have model news and every news belongs to an user:

```
class News extends Model {
(...)

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_user_id');
    }

(...)
```

I also have a comment model and also every comment belongs to an user:

```
class Comment extends Model {
(...)

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

(...)
}
```

In the show-function of the NewsController I'm getting the news with the comments:

```
    public function show($id)
    {

        $news = News::with('user', 'comments.user')->where('id', $id)->first();

        return view('news.show', compact(['news']));
    }
```

This works just fine. The issue is, that I have a lot of requests for the same user. It queries a subquery for the news and a subquery for the comments for the same user_ids.

Is this correct? How I can optimize this?

Best regards

**Update**

The show-function looks like this:

```
        $news = News::with(
            'user:id,name',
            'comments:id,commentable_id,content,ip,user_id,created_at,updated_at',
            'comments.user:id,name',
            'comments.replies:id,commentable_id,parent_id,content,ip,user_id,created_at,updated_at',
            'comments.replies.user:id,name', 'comments.replies.user.media:id',
            'comments.user.media:id',
            'comments.reactions:user_id,comment_id,reaction', 'comments.replies.reactions:user_id,comment_id,reaction')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first(['id', 'heading', 'author_user_id', 'content', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);

        return view('news.show', compact(['news']));
```

Comment: I don't think you can optimize this (in an elegant and worthwhile way). But I also think it doesn't matter, because your statement will _only_ perform 4 queries. If you don't load _all_ your `News` models (i.e. `get()` instead of `first()`), it really doesn't matter. The current query using `first()` will only load one user twice at max anyway.

Comment: It's growing very fast. I also have spatie's media library which I also have to eager load with 'user.media' and 'comments.user.media'. This seems very redundant and incorrect. Is this really the best way?

Comment: As said, if you load only one news post with its user and the media and what-not, it doesn't really matter. If you load 100+ news posts with users, their comments with users and all the other stuff, it _might_ be worthwhile investing some time in optimization. But I have to be honest, it isn't trivial and it is also not advisable to rebuild framework built-in functionality just for performance.

Comment: I edited my post with current show function of controller. I hope it's not so bad.